# git mac application

Tags: macos, github

So, I Just started to use GitHub, and I downloaded the application. And If I do commit something of to my github it uses my username of my computer, how do I change it to use the username of my github account?

So Question: How do you get the GitHub application (mac) to use your own github account username instead of your computers account username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the github application, click Github -> Preferences, and verify what your name is set to.

You can also see what name your git repo will use from the command line.

```
cd /your/git/repo
git config user.name
```

If you want to change the user name for just that repo...

```
cd /your/git/repo
git config user.name "joe smoe"
```

If you want to change your user name for every repo

```
git config --global user.name "joe smoe"
```

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git

Lastly, double check 'how' you are pushing up your commits. You may be using https which behaves differently than ssh. I can't say for sure how http behaves because I always use ssh.